# html 5 marquee tag error in w3c validation

Tags: html, w3c-validation, marquee

I have some text in marquee tag.

```
<marquee direction="left" scrollamount="4">
 Test Test Test Test Test
</marquee>
```

I am using html 5 and css 3. When i check my html in w3c validator, it shows the following error.

```
 Element marquee not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

        <marquee direction="left" scrollamount="4">
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You are using HTML5 and CSS3, as well as `marquee` that went out of fashion 15 years ago? ;)

Comment: marquee??...in html5 is deprecated! Use CSS3 animation for the same results!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marquee tag is not html5 (is not html at all, but Microsoft proprietary tag from 1995)

you can :

- use javascript to animate your text
- use css animation ([fully browser compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation))
- use [css3 marquee](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/) (not fully browser compatible)
- use marquee and ignore W3C warning (marquee is [full browser compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee#browser_compatibility), even in iOS safari!)
- don't use marquee effect (it's ugly)

Beware of the W3C validator: it doesn't always know all the W3C specifications!

Answer (score 3):

The marquee tag has been made obsolete in HTML5, but has returned in CSS3 (see
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/).

Comment: Have you some info about css3 marquee browsers compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 Marquee instead of it

**html**

```
<p class="marquee"><span>This is your sample text.</span></p>
```

**css**

```
/* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    text-indent: 0;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```