# Marquee tag in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, css

marquee tag with continuous scrolling image without any gap
How to remove the gap at the end of image.

```
<marquee Width="80%" behavior="alternate" direction ="left">
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="75px" Width="500px" ImageUrl='captcha.ashx'/>
</marquee>
```

I want continuous image without any gap.
Means it shows like continuous images but we are just used single image scrolling without gap...

Comment: "Marquee tag is not HTML5 (is not html at all, but Microsoft 1995 proprietary tag)" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15130970/28004 There are plenty of **infinite horizontal carousels** out there, just choose one.

Comment: Please do _not_ use the marquee tag. It's held up as an example of bad "html" and specifically of how non-standard/proprietary tags have made it harder to get standards-compliant browsers